# How to block port 8080

Tags: apache, tomcat

I'd like to block port 8080, because people are able to access my website at www.foo.com:8080, which I don't want. People should only be able to access www.foo.com. I'm using Apache on port 80 and mod_proxy to redirect calls to Tomcat on 8080.

I'm kind of at a loss. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just use a firewall?

Comment: @SLaks thanks! are there any docs that i should be looking at? i'm not sure how to start.

Comment: That depends what firewall you use.

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 1):

Try using [mod_proxy_ajp](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html) instead for request forwarding to Tomcat. Then configure the Tomcat instance with an [AJP connectior](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/ajp.html) only (and no [HTTP connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html)). This way, it cannot be accessed directly with a browser.

Anyway it's always a good idea to introduce a firewall as mentioned in the comments, for only exposing services you want to be available.